# Android: given crash reports, anyway to contact user?

Tags: android

The Android Market Developer Console automatically provides stack traces for crashes.  This is an amazing feature.  However, I would love to be able to contact the user to inquire about exact scenario that caused the crash.  I don't see any way to get user information from the crash report, am I missing anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can get is:

- the stacktrace
- the message the user entered

It is anonymous.